# Rails, disable cookies/sessions for some controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies, devise

I have an application which has both web and api, but I need to disable cookies/sessions for api controller, because devise authenticates user from session, but I need to authenticate user only from data provided in request. I found suggested solution `before_action -> { request.session_options[:skip] = true }` for api controllers, but this didn't work, it seems like this hook is working only for new sessions but not skips existing. I use rails 4 and devise gem for authentication. Also I found solution to disable cookies/sessions in `config/application.rb` but I don't need to disable sessions for whole application, only for api controllers.

**Solution**

According to answer in this question [Disable Cookies in Rails 3.x app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247257/disable-cookies-in-rails-3-x-app)
I solved it by adding

```
after_filter :skip_set_cookies_header

def skip_set_cookies_header
  request.session_options = {}
end
```

to my API controller.