# Removing Set-Cookie headers from response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I'm trying to remove `Set-Cookie` headers for any kind of `HTTP` response of my app.

As advised in the article below :

[Rails 3 disabling session cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435494/rails-3-disabling-session-cookies)

I added a "middleware app" to make it. Unfortunately, I observe that some of these headers are still in the response!

Theses `Set-Cookie` headers are in fact the cookies set by an other app (and that's normal as the two apps share these cookies)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!