# How do I prevent Rails from creating a session?

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, devise

I've got a Rails app for which I'm storing sessions in the database using [activerecord-session_store](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store).  I want to prevent the creation of sessions for users that aren't logged in, because right now every crawler that hits the front page of the site gets a session that persists in the DB.

My app uses Rails 4.2.0, activerecord-session_store 0.1.1, and Devise 3.5.2.

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 5.2.0 use:

```
request.session_options[:skip] = true
```

May result in `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error when submitting sign in or sign up forms. Validating authenticity tokens in `protect_from_forgery` seems to rely on the session. Quickfix: Disable in controller (eg. SessionsController):

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:create]
```

In order for sign out to work:

```
skip_after_action :skip_session, only: [:destroy]
```

Answer (score 5):

Session creation is handled by Rack and the [`commit_session` method in Rack::Session::Abstract::ID](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L331) provides an option to drop the session.  I wrote a filter method in my `ApplicationController` to drop the session if Devise's `current_user` isn't defined:

```
after_filter :skip_session

def skip_session
  unless current_user
    request.session_options = {drop: true}
  end
end
```

This prevents session creation<sup>1</sup>, but still allows sessions for logged in users.  This even allows users to login (pretty important)—they visit the login page without a session but upon submitting the form Devise sets `current_user` before this filter runs, thereby creating the session.

<sup>1: actually, the session is created and just not committed; in my case committing is to the DB, but if you use Rails' default cookie sessions, this would prevent sending the session cookie.</sup>

Comment: `after_action` instead of `after_filter` in newer versions of Rails. I also used `request.session_options[:skip] = true` instead.