# How do I prevent devise from storing sessions when basic auth is used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, basic-authentication

Disclaimer: I am a relatively novice RoR developer.

My rails 4 web app supports a RESTful API. I am using devise, and the API authenticates with basic auth without any use of keys/tokens (so basic auth must be used on each request). It works fine, except for this: If you are logged out and hit the API in the browser it stores a session, so then if you go back to the web app, you are logged in. This is not the behavior I want. The user should be redirected to the sign-in page when they hit the API and then hit the web app (unless they were already logged in to begin with). So how to I prevent devise from storing a session when basic auth is used?

Relevant code: In the application controller I have:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

And in devise.rb I have:

```
config.http_authenticatable = true
```

Comment: I found this question that may be helpful to you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435494/rails-3-disabling-session-cookies essentially it looks like you'll need to configure the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!,except: [("whatever actions you want the user to see without being logged in")]
```